# Multiple system calls from PID 0 in Windows

Tags: windows, security, process

Recently, one of my old PC at home lags at times. I open the Process Monitor (from sysinternals.com) and find multiple system calls from a process with PID 0, including CreateFile operation. I thought PID 0 belongs to system idle process but now I am confused. I am worried that my computer has caught some virus or being monitored by some hackers. So what on earth is this process of PID 0? Is it possible for   hackers to hide their operations in this process?

By the way, the OS is a 3-year-old Vista SP2 (32-bit).

Comment: ProcMon is probably reporting 0 for IO requests it can't tie to a specific process.

Comment: Make sure you're running Process Monitor with admin privileges.

Comment: I was running with admin